# How to Running Total for condition function in Crystal Report

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports, conditional-statements, formula, cumulative-sum

Hi I use Crystal Report 2016,

I have Running Total of number values (Number of hours - `#P.soucet0` ). Then I have Formula field with formula
  `if {#P.soucet0}>50 then {#P.soucet0}-50
else 0`

How can I get Total of this Formula?
Running Total doesn't show it for Evaluation and When I use Formula Field to Sum it: `sum({@if})`
, it says that You can't sum this Function.

Can someone please help me?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to create another running total field that sums up your formula?

Comment: Yes I have, but it doesn't offers me to choose the Formula

http://i.imgur.com/NrwnzM5.jpg

Comment: I am not sure about "Running Total of number values (Number of hours - #P.soucet0 )" and " formula  if {#P.soucet0}>50 then {#P.soucet0}-50
else 0". Do they relate in any way? As far as i know Crystal can't sum something that is already summarized.

Comment: It is solved.  I used 3 variables.  

1st - that sums my if function with "virtual" numberVar. And I placed it into detail.  

"WhilePrintingRecords;
shared numberVar RunT;
RunT:= RunT + {@if}"



2nd that nuls that numberVar and this I placed it into Group Footer. 

"whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar RunT;
RunT:=0"

And last one that displays the numberVar. 

"WhilePrintingRecords;
shared numbervar RunT;
RunT"

And this I also placed in Footer. And it works.